# Solve the string expression using Stack

Tags: java, string, stack, solution

I'm trying to expand the given string like the below sample test cases.

**Sample Input and Output**

```
Input : a(b(c){2}){2}d
Output:  abccbccd

Input:  ((x){3}(y){2}z){2}
Output: xxxyyzxxxyyz
```

Below code works fine for the above test cases, but I would like to know if there are any better approach than this, since I'm not confident with this solution. Any solution using `ArrayList` as a stack is welcomed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.next();
    String temp = "";
    String alpha = "";
    ArrayList<String> stack = new ArrayList<>();
        
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
            
        if (ch == '(') {
            stack.add(""+ch);
        } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
            alpha += ch;

            if (!stack.isEmpty() && !stack.get(stack.size()-1).equals("(")) {
                alpha = stack.remove(stack.size()-1) + alpha;
            }

            stack.add(alpha);
            alpha = "";
        } else if (ch == ')') {
            temp = stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
                
            for(; !stack.get(stack.size()-1).equals("(");) {
                temp = stack.remove(stack.size()-1) + temp;
            }

            stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
            stack.add(temp);
        } else if (ch == '{') {
            i++;
            temp = stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
            String t = temp;

            if(s.charAt(i)=='0') {
                temp = "";
            }

            for(int j = 1; j < s.charAt(i)-48; j++) {
                temp += t;
            }

            i++;
            if (s.charAt(i) == '}') {
                stack.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print(stack);
}
```

Comment: Assuming your solution works, and you just want some pointers, this question might work better on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: You might want to clarify your rules. These produce different outputs but I would expect them to be the same. `(a)b{3} vs a(b){3}`  In each case `a` and `b` seem to be isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `ArrayList` is the most suitable approach for your code. Since Java 1.5, you can use `StringBuilder` to concatenate characters inside a string buffer. Your code will be much faster and use less memory.

With a `String`instance:

```
str += other;
```

is equivalent to:

```
str = str + other;
```

, so the operation is **O(str.length() + other.length())**.

With a `StringBuilder` instance:

```
str.append(other)
```

The operation is only **O(other.length())**.

Same thing for the left-hand concatenation. The instruction:

```
str = other + str;
```

will be replaced by:

```
str.insert(0, other);
```

Your code would look like this (I added a `switch-case` which is slightly faster than multiple `if` statements):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.next();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder alpha = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> stack = new ArrayList<>();
        
    for (int i = 0, len = s.length(); i < len; i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        switch(ch) {
        case '(':
            stack.add("" + ch);
            break;
        case ')':
            temp = new StringBuilder(stack.remove(stack.size() - 1));
            for(; !stack.get(stack.size()-1).equals("(");) {
                String last = stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
                temp.insert(0, last);
            }

            stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
            stack.add(temp.toString());

            break;
        case '{':
            i++;
            temp = new StringBuilder(stack.remove(stack.size() - 1));
            String t = temp.toString();
            if (s.charAt(i) == '0')
                temp.setLength(0);

            for(int j = 1; j < s.charAt(i) - 48; j++)
                temp.append(t);

            i++;
            if (s.charAt(i) == '}')
                stack.add(temp.toString());

            break;
        default:
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                alpha.append(ch);

                if (!stack.isEmpty() && !stack.get(stack.size()-1).equals("(")) {
                    String last = stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
                    alpha.insert(0, last);
                }

                stack.add(alpha.toString());
                alpha.setLength(0); // Clears the string buffer
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(String.join("", stack));
}
```